# Обращение к методу Nullable переменной в Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пытаюсь перевести следующий код из java в kotlin:

```
private LGMThread lgmThread;

if (!lgmThread.isThreadStarted()) {
    lgmThread.start();
} else {
    lgmThread.openChannel();
}
```

Вместе с автоматическим конвертером кода Android Studio я перевела это в:

```
private var lgmThread: LGMThread? = null

if (!lgmThread.isThreadStarted()) {
        lgmThread?.start()
} else {
        lgmThread?.openChannel()
}
```

однако при этом AS ругается на выражение `!lgmThread.isThreadStarted()`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовала исправить это следующим образом:

```
lgmThread?.let {
    if (!lgmThread.isThreadStarted()) {
        lgmThread?.start()
    } else {
        lgmThread?.openChannel()
    }
}
```

однако это не решает проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И код

```
if (lgmThread != null) { 
    if (!lgmThread.isThreadStarted()) {
        lgmThread?.start()
    } else {
        lgmThread?.openChannel()
    }
}
```

приводит к точно такому же результату.

Код

```
if (!lgmThread?.isThreadStarted()) {
            lgmThread?.start()
} else {
            lgmThread?.openChannel()
}
```

также приводит к другой ошибке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С оператором `!!`, конечно, ошибка исчезает:

```
if (!lgmThread!!.isThreadStarted()) {
     lgmThread?.start()
} else {
     lgmThread?.openChannel()
}
```

однако я не хочу использовать этот способ. Как правильно избавиться от этой ошибки, не прибегая к оператору `!!`?

Comment: `!lgmThread?.isThreadStarted()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, забыла указать это в посте, но это я тоже уже пробовала. И это так же приводит к ошибке: "Only safe (?.) or non-null assserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver type of Boolean?". Добавила скриншот в пост.

Comment: А если `!lgmThread?.isThreadStarted() ?: false`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как `lgmThread` имеет тип `LGMThread?`, то и возвращаемое методом `lgmThread?.isThreadStarted()` значение будет иметь тип `Boolean?`

В таком случае в блоке `if` вы можете проверять `lgmThread?.isThreadStarted()` на **true**, **false** и **null**

Соответственно, кусок кода может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
private var lgmThread: LGMThread? = null

if (lgmThread?.isThreadStarted() == false) {
   lgmThread?.start()
} else {
   lgmThread?.openChannel()
}
```

---

P.S. Но будьте внимательны, так как в таком случае код в блоке `else` выполнится при `lgmThread?.isThreadStarted()` равном **true** и **null**

Comment: `lgmThread?.start()` - здесь он уже точно не null.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я в курсе, но `?` обязателен и IDE об этом должна предупредить

Answer (score 4):

Ваша мысль с `let` была в верном направлении, только вы не изучили теорию как следует. Такое решение гораздо элегантнее.

```
lgmThread?.let {
    if (!it.isThreadStarted()) {
        it.start()
    } else {
        it.openChannel()
    }
}
```

Или `run`

```
lgmThread?.run {
    if (!isThreadStarted()) {
        start()
    } else {
        openChannel()
    }
}
```